# How to sort categories by name alphabetically?

Tags: php, sorting, magento-1.7, layered-navigation

How could I sort the categories under layered navigation in Magento 1.7 by name instead the position? I need to sort the categories not the products list.

I have this:

```
Categories:
Category B
Category D
Category A
```

I would like to have this:

```
Categories:
Category A
Category B
Category C
```

I've tried to change the options via administration frontend settings but it's not working. And also I've tried to change the catalog.xml as follows but it's not working:

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection"><dir>desc</dir></action>
    <action method="setDefaultOrder"><dir>name</dir></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: I'm looking for a solution using the xml instead to change the template file.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Code

```
<reference name="product_list_toolbar">
    <action method="setDefaultDirection"><string>desc</string></action>
    <action method="setDefaultOrder"><string>name</string></action>
</reference>
```

Comment: I tried it. Other filters in the layered navigation are sorted fine. But the categories list is the only one which is not sorted by name.